# How do I sync a mongolab database to a local mongodb database using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

guys. I have a local database on mongodb. I also have an identical db on mongolab. In the mongolab db, I append document/entries regularly. What I want to do is to sync these changes on my local mongodb collection. I'm currently thinking of doing a periodic query on the mongolab collection to see if the document count increases and if it does, I would know that there are new documents to account for.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks!